# STM32F105 bootloader: jump address problem, bootloader loops

Tags: stm32, bootloader

Problem: The bootloader loops.
I think there is a problem with the transfer address.

The entry point of the main program is at:
[image]

This is how the entry point to the main program looks like in the microcontroller memory (0x801F24D)
[image]

The address of the transition to the main program looks like this
[image]
Jump address to main program is not equal 0x801F24C (Reset_Handler main program has an address 0x801F24C)

Jump function code:

```
#define MAIN_PROGRAM_START_ADDRESS  0x08010000    
void ExecMainFW(void)
    {
        uint32_t app_jump_address;
        typedef void(*pFunction)(void);             
        pFunction Jump_To_Application;              
    
         __disable_irq();                           
    
        app_jump_address = *( uint32_t*) (MAIN_PROGRAM_START_ADDRESS + 4);      
        //app_jump_address &= ~(uint32_t)0x01;
        Jump_To_Application = (pFunction)app_jump_address;                      
        __set_MSP(*(volatile  uint32_t*) MAIN_PROGRAM_START_ADDRESS);          
        Jump_To_Application();
        while(1){}
    }
```

If I run the code as shown above, the loader will loop. The controller seems to reload itself as soon as it calls the function Jump_To_Application().

If I uncomment the line app_jump_address &= ~(uint32_t)0x01;  I get the correct jump address 0x801F24C  but then the loader loops at HardFault_Handler().
I don't understand where is my mistake? help me please.

Main app settings:

```
/* Memories definition */
MEMORY
{
  RAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 64K
  FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8010000,   LENGTH = 64K
}

int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
    __disable_irq();
    SCB->VTOR = MAIN_PROGRAM_START_ADDRESS;
    __enable_irq();
  /* USER CODE END 1 */
  //...
  while(1)
  {
    //...
  }
}
```

Oddly and I don't know why, but everything works if I remove this line __disable_irq();

Comment: Have you said to your main application that it does not start from start of flash but at some memory address after bootloader? Otherwise it dors not know where in the flash it exists.

Comment: Yes, I specified the address of the program start to the main application (changed the linker settings), shifted the interrupt vectors.

Comment: The LSbit of the jump address being set (giving you an address of  0x801F24**D** instead of 0x801F24**C** is expected. [It tells the core that it should run in Thumb mode (instead of ARM mode) when it starts to execute at that location](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/293238/arm-mode-and-thumb-mode-makes-the-pcs-bit-0).
What else do you have in your main application `main()` function? Do you have an infinite loop there to prevent `main` from ever returning?

Comment: Single step and see what actually happens

Comment: @Chris Stratton  
The debugger exits because it doesn't know anything about the jump address.

Comment: @brhans  Yes, I have an infinite loop. The main program works fine. I can run it with the debugger. The main program is launched from address 0x8010000

Comment: Debug without symbols and manually cross reference assembly listings of bootloader and main program.  A *proper* debugger will not "exit" !